# Symfony, unique entity validator get error without reason

Tags: symfony, validation, doctrine, unique-constraint

My UniqueEntity validator throw errors without reason. When try to create new User I get error that properties username and email are already in use. In database there no such entries with these parameters.

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table("users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, errorPath="username", message="Username already in use", inheritedFields=true)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, errorPath="email", message="Email already in use")
 * @ORMInheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements TwoFactorInterface
{
```

These properties are declared in `BaseUser` model that is from FOS User Bundle.

```
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($user);
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return new Response($this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($errors, 'json'), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Did you `var_dump()` the object you're trying to persist to check if it's containing the expected values ?

Comment: I use xdebug and the User object is filled-up with correct values before persist.

Comment: Do you mind [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52662307/edit) your question and add the relevant part in the controller where you're saving your entity?